# How to disable value of the field not used warning for logger field in eclipse/java

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I've been using the logging framework SL4J and it has become a habit to have a logger variable available in every class:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Clazz.class);
```

But I'm also cleaning up code and I want to get rid of the specific warning:

> The value of the field Clazz.logger is not used

Of course, the simple solution would be to delete the field. But what I would like to do is disable this warning in Eclipse for the entire project, just for the logger field.

I do not want to disable this warning for fields that have a different name than "logger". I also do not want to write: @SuppressWarnings("unused") every time I use a logger.

Is this possible? If so, how can i do this?

Comment: Do you have a field `Clazz.logger`?

Comment: Personally I use `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` because it is then clear to other people reading the code that this is intentional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disable the warning for this specific case.

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. Create a code template `slf4j` that adds a logger to a class. This means you can quickly delete and add the field as you need.
2. Use [project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) to have the logger field added to the class on an as-needed basis (plus a lot of other goodies).

I'm using this code template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><templates><template autoinsert="true" context="java-members" deleted="false" description="Slf4j Logger" enabled="true" name="log">private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);${imp:import(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory)}${imap:import(org.slf4j.Logger)}</template></templates>
```

Paste it into a file and import it in Eclipse.

Comment: @aaron thanks for the template :) works great and solves the issue for me, of unused logger, now I can just remove them.